# Remove duplicate detail transaction (header detail store procedure)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, master-detail

I have problem when creating header detail transaction in store procedure. Assume **1** header contain **3** details transaction. If I want to get invoice I must join some table for getting the formula.

```
USE [M_TENANT]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[generate_billingv2]    Script Date: 07/02/2020 09:32:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[generate_billingv2]
AS
--exec generate_billingv2
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @genbill_nochar INT
    ,@OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@NAME_CHAR VARCHAR(80)
    ,@opt_utility_detail NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@MD_BILLING_ID_INT INT
    ,@BILLING_ID_UTILITY INT
    ,@OPT_UTILITY_AMT NUMERIC
    ,@BILLING_ID_FORMULA INT
    ,@FORMULA_PRICE NUMERIC
    ,@FORMULA_VA NUMERIC
    ,@FORMULA_NAME VARCHAR(50)
    ,@MD_FORMULA_PERCENTAGE DECIMAL(18, 3)
    ,@bill_TYPE INT
    ,@BASE_INVOICE_AMT NUMERIC
    ,@OPT_UTILITY_USED NUMERIC
    ,@ABODEMEN NUMERIC
    ,@UNIT_LB DECIMAL(18, 3)
    ,@TAX_UTILITY NUMERIC(18, 3)
    ,@TOTAL_UTILITY NUMERIC(18, 3)
    ,@OPT_GENBILL_NOCHAR VARCHAR(50)
    ,@NOUNIT_CHAR CHAR(20)
    ,@OPT_GENBILL_STATUS_INT INT
    ,@OPT_GENBILL_TRX_DATE DATE
    ,@OPT_UTILITY_TRX_DATE DATE
    ,@OPT_TRANS_ID_INT INT
    ,@OPT_GENERATE_BY VARCHAR(50)
    ,@MD_FORMULA_PRICE NUMERIC
    ,@USAGE DECIMAL(18, 2)
    ,@OPT_FLOOR CHAR(10)
    ,@MD_FORMULA_NAME VARCHAR(50)
    ,@OPT_START NUMERIC
    ,@OPT_BILL_END NUMERIC
    ,@OPT_START_DATE DATE
    ,@OPT_END_DATE DATE
    ,@FORMULA_PERCENTAGE DECIMAL(18, 2)

SET @BASE_INVOICE_AMT = 0
SET @TAX_UTILITY = 0
SET @TOTAL_UTILITY = 0
SET @OPT_GENBILL_STATUS_INT = 0
SET @OPT_GENBILL_TRX_DATE = GETDATE()
SET @OPT_GENERATE_BY = 'AUTO'

DECLARE bill_header CURSOR
FOR
SELECT a.OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
    ,a.NOUNIT_CHAR
    ,b.UNIT_LB
    ,b.NAME_CHAR
    ,b.OPT_FLOOR
    ,a.OPT_TRANS_ID_INT
    ,a.OPT_UTILITY_TRX_DATE
    ,0 AS BASE_INVOICE
    ,0 AS TAX_UTILITY
    ,0 AS TOTAL_ULTILITY
FROM OPT_UTILITY a
INNER JOIN OPT_TRANS b ON a.OPT_TRANS_ID_INT = b.OPT_TRANS_ID_INT
WHERE a.OPT_GENBILL_STATUS_INT = 0

OPEN bill_header

FETCH NEXT
FROM bill_header
INTO @OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
    ,@NOUNIT_CHAR
    ,@UNIT_LB
    ,@NAME_CHAR
    ,@OPT_FLOOR
    ,@OPT_TRANS_ID_INT
    ,@OPT_UTILITY_TRX_DATE
    ,@BASE_INVOICE_AMT
    ,@TAX_UTILITY
    ,@TOTAL_UTILITY

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --HEADER TRANSACTION
    --PRINT 'ini header'+'-'+ @OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR  
    SET @OPT_GENBILL_NOCHAR = convert(VARCHAR, (
                SELECT 'KALINV' + convert(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE())) + REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(RTRIM(invoiced_count))) + RTRIM(invoiced_count)
                FROM counter_table
                ));

    INSERT INTO OPT_GENBILL (
        OPT_GENBILL_NOCHAR
        ,OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
        ,NOUNIT_CHAR
        ,NAME_CHAR
        ,LB
        ,BASE_UTILITY
        ,TAX_UTILITY
        ,TOTAL_UTILITY
        ,OPT_GENBILL_STATUS_INT
        ,OPT_GENBILL_TRX_DATE
        ,OPT_UTILITY_TRX_DATE
        ,OPT_TRANS_ID_INT
        ,OPT_GENERATE_BY
        )
    VALUES (
        @OPT_GENBILL_NOCHAR
        ,@OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
        ,@NOUNIT_CHAR
        ,@NAME_CHAR
        ,@UNIT_LB
        ,@BASE_INVOICE_AMT
        ,@TAX_UTILITY
        ,@TOTAL_UTILITY
        ,@OPT_GENBILL_STATUS_INT
        ,@OPT_GENBILL_TRX_DATE
        ,@OPT_UTILITY_TRX_DATE
        ,@OPT_TRANS_ID_INT
        ,@OPT_GENERATE_BY
        )

    DECLARE bill_detail CURSOR
    FOR
    SELECT C.MD_BILLING_ID_INT AS BILL_TYPE
        ,a.OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
        ,a.MD_BILLING_ID_INT
        ,b.MD_FORMULA_PRICE
        ,b.MD_FORMULA_NAME
        ,b.MD_FORMULA_PERCENTAGE
        ,b.MD_FORMULA_PJU_ABD AS ABODEMEN
        ,b.MD_FORMULA_VA AS FORMULA_VA
        ,a.OPT_BILL_END - a.OPT_UTILITY_AMT AS OPT_START
        ,a.OPT_BILL_END
        ,a.OPT_UTILITY_AMT AS USAGE
        ,a.OPT_START_DATE
        ,a.OPT_END_DATE
    FROM OPT_UTILITY_DETAIL a
    INNER JOIN MD_FORMULA b ON a.MD_BILLING_ID_INT = b.MD_FORMULA_ID_INT
    INNER JOIN MD_BILLING_TYPE c ON b.MD_BILLING_ID_INT = c.MD_BILLING_ID_INT
    WHERE a.OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR = @OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR

    OPEN bill_detail

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM bill_detail
    INTO @BILL_TYPE
        ,@OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
        ,@MD_BILLING_ID_INT
        ,@MD_FORMULA_PRICE
        ,@MD_FORMULA_NAME
        ,@MD_FORMULA_PERCENTAGE
        ,@ABODEMEN
        ,@FORMULA_VA
        ,@OPT_START
        ,@OPT_BILL_END
        ,@USAGE
        ,@OPT_START_DATE
        ,@OPT_END_DATE

    --IF  exists(select TOP 1*  from OPT_GENBILL  where OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR=@OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR)
    --BEGIN
    --  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    --  DEALLOCATE bill_detail
    --  RAISERROR('invoice sudah pernah generate ',16,-1,@OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR)
    --  RETURN
    --END
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
        PRINT '         <<None>>'

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --SET @BASE_INVOICE_AMT = CASE WHEN @BILL_TYPE=3 AND @USAGE<=40 THEN 
        --                                                  ((@ABODEMEN*(@FORMULA_VA/1000)*@FORMULA_PRICE)+ ((@ABODEMEN*(@FORMULA_VA/1000)*@FORMULA_PRICE)*@FORMULA_PERCENTAGE))
        --                             when @bill_TYPE=3 and @USAGE>40 then
        --                           ((@USAGE*(@FORMULA_VA/1000)*@FORMULA_PRICE)+ ((@USAGE*(@FORMULA_VA/1000)*@FORMULA_PRICE)*@FORMULA_PERCENTAGE)) 
        --                           when @bill_TYPE=2 then ((@USAGE*@FORMULA_PRICE)+@ABODEMEN)
        --                           when @bill_TYPE=1 then @UNIT_LB*@FORMULA_PRICE
        --                            else 0 end
        --print @OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
        -- print @BILL_TYPE
        -- print @USAGE
        -- print @ABODEMEN
        -- print @FORMULA_PRICE
        -- print @FORMULA_VA
        -- print @FORMULA_PERCENTAGE
        INSERT INTO OPT_GENBILL_DETAIL (
            OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
            ,NOUNIT_CHAR
            ,OPT_START_DATE
            ,OPT_END_DATE
            ,OPT_BILL_START
            ,OPT_BILL_END
            ,OPT_UTILITY_AMT
            ,OPT_GENBILL_NOCHAR
            )
        SELECT @OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
            ,@NOUNIT_CHAR
            ,OPT_START_DATE
            ,OPT_END_DATE
            ,OPT_BILL_END - OPT_UTILITY_AMT
            ,OPT_BILL_END
            ,CASE 
                WHEN @BILL_TYPE = 3
                    AND @USAGE <= 40
                    THEN ((@ABODEMEN * (@FORMULA_VA / 1000) * @FORMULA_PRICE) + ((@ABODEMEN * (@FORMULA_VA / 1000) * @FORMULA_PRICE) * @FORMULA_PERCENTAGE))
                WHEN @bill_TYPE = 3
                    AND @USAGE > 40
                    THEN ((@USAGE * (@FORMULA_VA / 1000) * @FORMULA_PRICE) + ((@USAGE * (@FORMULA_VA / 1000) * @FORMULA_PRICE) * @FORMULA_PERCENTAGE))
                WHEN @bill_TYPE = 2
                    THEN ((@USAGE * @FORMULA_PRICE) + @ABODEMEN)
                ELSE 0
                END
            ,@OPT_GENBILL_NOCHAR
        FROM OPT_UTILITY_DETAIL
        WHERE OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR = @OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR

        FETCH NEXT
        FROM bill_detail
        INTO @BILL_TYPE
            ,@OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
            ,@MD_BILLING_ID_INT
            ,@MD_FORMULA_PRICE
            ,@MD_FORMULA_NAME
            ,@MD_FORMULA_PERCENTAGE
            ,@ABODEMEN
            ,@FORMULA_VA
            ,@OPT_START
            ,@OPT_BILL_END
            ,@USAGE
            ,@OPT_START_DATE
            ,@OPT_END_DATE
    END

    CLOSE bill_detail

    DEALLOCATE bill_detail

    UPDATE counter_table
    SET invoiced_count = invoiced_count + 1

    UPDATE OPT_UTILITY
    SET OPT_GENBILL_STATUS_INT = 1
    WHERE OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR = @OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR

    -- Get the next vendor.  
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM bill_header
    INTO @OPT_UTILITY_NOCHAR
        ,@NOUNIT_CHAR
        ,@UNIT_LB
        ,@NAME_CHAR
        ,@OPT_FLOOR
        ,@OPT_TRANS_ID_INT
        ,@OPT_UTILITY_TRX_DATE
        ,@BASE_INVOICE_AMT
        ,@TAX_UTILITY
        ,@TOTAL_UTILITY
END

CLOSE bill_header;

DEALLOCATE bill_header;

COMMIT TRANSACTION

RETURN
```

But the result **3** detail generating 9 details rows.

Comment: Firstly you have not provided the related table schema, sample data, current output and expected output. Also, this is a rather long query with cursor for anyone to understand and debug. Please do consider rewrite it using set-based approach

Comment: If you're getting three headers generated, make sure that the select in your first cursor, both runs and returns a single row. I suspect it's returning multiple rows.

Comment: Could you tell ,how to correct